# Set a camera to free fall like a Rigid Body?

Tags: camera, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I want to capture freely falling objects from their reference frame. i.e. to have the camera freely falling due to gravity in the exact same manner.  Is there a simple way to make a camera free fall just like a Rigid Body?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: animated gif showing the camera falling with the cubs]

No python needed.

Simply add a [Copy Location constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/constraints/transform/copy_location.html) to the camera. Set the *Target* to an object with an active rigid body. (I simply duplicated one of my colorful cubes and moved it back from the rest of the bunch. *Remember to turn the visibility off*). That will get the camera to fall down with gravity.

To get the nice camera shake when it hits the ground we need two more constraints. A [Copy Rotation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/constraints/transform/copy_rotation.html) constraint and a [Track To](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html) constraint.
The *Copy Rotation* is copying the rotation of the same cube the camera is glued to, that gets the real shake from the impact with the ground. (I have the *Influence* of that set to 0.5 just to tone it down a bit.)

The *Track To* is to keep all my cube in frame. (you can see how much the cubes tumble, and without this constraint the camera would do that too.)

These are my constraints on the camera. Do note the object "Cube.001" is the cube I moved off screen for the camera, and the "Cube" is simply one in the middle of the pack.
[image: constraints on the camera]

Answer (score 3):

[image: final]

You can do this even easier. Just Parent Camera to one of the Cubes faces.

1. Select **Cubes** face.
2. Place **Cursor** on it - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > **Cursor to Selected**.
3. Select **Camera** and place it on **Cursor** position - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > **Selection to Cursor**.
4. Select **Camera** first then **Cube** with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > **Object**.
5. Done.

> Note: Based on the initial Camera position/face selected you will need
>   to set Camera rotation accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a cube, letting it fall and baking its keyframes. I then used the cubes baked positions as the camera's. Since this is not exactly what I wanted, I'm leaving the question open. My code is here for anyone to use:

```
import bpy

cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube.009']
camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
sce = bpy.context.scene

for i in range(300):
    sce.frame_set(i)
    camera.location.z = cube.location.z
    camera.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', index = 2, frame = i)
```